# devbridge jQuery-Autocomplete in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to make an ajax search with jquery autocomplete but it doesn't work

this is my controller:

```
$search_term = Input::get('search');
$search = Topic::select('topic_title')->where('topic_title', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_term.'%')->get();

foreach ($search as $v)
{
    $return_array[] = ['value'=>$v];
}
    return Response::json( array('suggestions'=>$return_array) );
```

This is my js:

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
serviceUrl: '/search',
 dataType: 'json',
type: 'GET',
getValue: "value",

onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
}
});
```

The problem is that it doesn't show anything, it only shows some stuff in my network :

> suggestions: [{value: {topic_title: "asddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddafffsdfs"}}, {value: {,…}},…]

Does anybody know how can i make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

In you case just do

```
$search = Topic::all();

foreach($search as $v)
{
  $return_array[] =  ["value"=>$v->topic_title,"data"=>$v->topic_title];
}

return response()->json(array("suggestions"=>$return_array));
```